# await - catch error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I'm getting

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 44): Error: fail
```

main.js

```
import { request } from './api'

async getData({ commit, state },  ids ){
  try {
    var x = await request(ids)
    commit('getData', x.data)
  } catch ( e ) {
    console.log('request failed get',e.code,e.errno)
  }
}
```

api.js

```
export async function request(type,url,ids){
  axios.get('localhost/data')
    .then(function (response) {
      return Promise.resolve(response.data)
    })
   .catch(function (e) {
     return Promise.reject(new Error('fail'))
  })
}
```

How can I handle the promise rejection? Shouldn't the try catch block catch the error from the await function here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up async/await with promises. In `api.js`, there is no need to use the *async* keyword. The *async* keyword makes it so that anything you return from the function is wrapped in a promise, which you don't need, since *axios.get* returns a promise already.

Also, you forgot to actually return the promise from Axios, your `request` function just returns *undefined*.

Lastly, you don't have to return promises from the *then* and *catch* methods, just return a value, or throw an error.

If you rewrite the function like this it should work as expected:

```
export function request(type,url,ids){
  return axios.get('localhost/data')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      throw new Error('fail')
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just noticed that I forgot the return function - ok I think I understand, I'm returning a promise inside a promise which is kinda useless